# Standard buttons on custom toolbar not visible

Tags: ms-word, customization, ribbon

In the customUI tool I created the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
        <ribbon>
        <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabHome">
        <group idMso="GroupFont" visible="false" />
        <group idMso="GroupParagraph" visible="false" />
        <group id="CustGrp1" label="MyGroup" insertBeforeMso="GroupStyles">
            <button idMso="TableInsertDialogWord" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="ConvertTextToTable" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="SpellingAndGrammar" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="AlignLeft" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="AlignCenter" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="Superscript" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="HyperlinkInsert" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="BookmarkInsert" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="AutoTextInsert" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="ReviewNewComment" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="SymbolsDialog" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="ParagraphMarks" showLabel="false" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I hide two groups and add one custom group. In this custom group I add only standard buttons using the proper idMSO (downloaded from MS). In Word I can only see five of the twelve buttons. What's wrong here? Are my id's incorrect?

Comment: Which buttons are showing up? Which version of Word is involved here? (The controls available might be version-specific).

Comment: Make sure you have "Show add-in user interface errors" activated in File/Options/Advanced, in the section "General" so that you can see any errors the Ribbon XML is triggering. I think you have the wrong control type for a number of entries. AlignLeft is a toggleButton not a button, for example.

Comment: Thanks Cindy! I changed the XML based on the specs in the Excel (not everything is a button, duh). All buttons, galleries and toggleButtons are showing up now. Only the button HyperlinkInsert keeps missing. We use Word365.

Answer (score 0):

We still have this issue with the latest Word in 2023.  I think its because the hyperlink button is now a custom dropdown.  While it is called a button by the ribbon config, its not really one.  You simply can't add it to a custom ribbon tab since Word 2016.

We worked around this by reimplementing the call to create the link.

It takes some code but you can reuse parts of Word such as the ribbon portion which uses the standard Word image:

```
<button id="linkId" label="Hyperlink" imageMso="HyperlinkInsert" onAction="yourMethod"/>
```

and we use the standard Word hyperlink UI which can be called within yourMethod() as

```
// Show the standard Word hyperlink dialog
var dialog = currentRange.Application.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogInsertHyperlink];

// In unit testing, this sets the timeout so the dialog disappears after a few seconds.
// The link is created when the user presses OK
object oTimeout = Util.InUnitTesting ? 1000 : Type.Missing;
dialog.Show(ref oTimeout);
```